# jQuery Ajax Request with Javascript alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a Javascript function in my .html file that uses [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method in itself. In the callback method 'success' of the AJAX request, there is a javascript alert() call.

```
  function test_server(test_url) {
    jQuery.get(test_url, function(data) {
      alert("You have received '" + data + "'");
    });
  }
```

As long as I did not click 'OK' in the alert box, the request seems to be not finished in my Firebug console.

Is the request-response cycle really not finished or does the process of the server that has sent the response hang up until the user clicks 'OK'?

PS: I am using Firefox 11.0 and Firebug 1.9.1

Comment: "the request seems to be not finished in my Firebug console" I don't understand this, I think when you recived the response, the request is finished

Comment: I've just realized that I got 200 OK (request is finished) however, because of the alert() call, the ajax call seems to be working and Firebug shows a loading gif until you click 'OK'.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem, it's a firebug implemention issue

Comment: Now I again tried with a single threaded server. I did not click 'OK' and then I requested another page from the server and, I got the page. Thus, yes, the request is finished.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's a sort of a bug of Firebug because the request has to be finished at this point.

(In Chrome it doesn't happen)

Comment: P.S: In my Firefox it doesn't happen (Firefox 10, Firebug 1.9.1)